# Why is the data unbind with modal window? /AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, modal-dialog

Can someone tell me.
I want to let reflect input data in modal window and parent window text.
But it's not reflected by making a modal window.
How will it be reflected?

#### HTML

```
<p><img src="***.jpg" alt="" ng-click="cover.show()"></p>
<p class="binding-field" id="title-box">{{titleBox}}</p>

<script id="templates/input-cover.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-modal-view>
..........
<ion-content class="input-area">
    <form action="">
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="titleBox">
        </label>
    </form>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-modal-view>
```

#### controllers.js

```
function inputCtrl($scope, $ionicModal) {
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/input-cover.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.cover = modal;
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it from the parent scope via resolve function. [doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Example:

code in **parentCtrl**:

```
var toEdit = $scope.model.selectedServers[0];

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'servers/templates/servers-new.tpl.html',
    controller: 'newServerCtrl',
    resolve: { // you sould pass it from here
        serverData: function () {
            return toEdit; 
        }
    }
});
```

code in **childCtrl**:

```
 $scope.newServer = serverData || { os: 2 }; // get serverData passed from the parentCtrl
```

hope it helps!

Just find an example on plnkr.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcMA47N1X9Hetj0Frilj?p=preview)